# how make Filename from Variable value

Tags: bash, files, codecs

Is there any bash code for making the file name from a Variable value?
ex\

```
x="IMP"
date > x.txt
```

output

```
IMP.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. On the bash command line, define a variable like this:

```
X="test.file"
```

and then create a file with this name like this:

```
touch "$X"
```

The quotes around the `$X` are present to take care of possible spaces in the filename.
Now `ls -A` will confirm you the existence of this file:

```
-rw-rw-r--  1 kubuntu kubuntu        0 Dez  2 01:06  test.file
```

And you can add content to this file like this:

```
date >> "$X"
```

which will add the output of `date` to the file.
Of course, the scope of this variable `X` is limited to the current bash/shell instance.

Comment: thank you its work 